# Parsing variables in and out of functions jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, function

i'm sure this is just a simple one, but its got me stumped on a few different projects now..  i have to keep declaring my variables, and i'm sure there is a better way to be doing things.

in the example below, i'm finding at the "#gender" stage "gender" is printing out fine, but "#age" stage "gender" is no longer defined &/or is not being carried through to the other function.

an example:

```
var gender;
var age;
var children;


$('#gender li:contains(Male)').click(function() {
  gender = "male";
  $('#age').show();
  $('span.jquery_out').text(gender);
});
$('#gender li:contains(Female)').click(function() {
gender = "female";
$('#age').show();
$('span.jquery_out').text(gender);
});

$('#age li:contains(1)').click(function() {
  var age = "1";
  $('#children').show();
  $('span.jquery_out').text(gender+" -> "+age);
});
$('#age li:contains(2)').click(function() {
  var age = "2";
  $('#children').show();
  $('span.jquery_out').text(gender+" -> "+age);
});
$('#age li:contains(3)').click(function() {
  var age = "3";
  $('#children').show();
  $('span.jquery_out').text(gender+" -> "+age);
});
$('#age li:contains(4)').click(function() {
  var age = "4";
  $('#children').show();
  $('span.jquery_out').text(gender+" -> "+age);
});
$('#age li:contains(5)').click(function() {
  var age = "5";
  $('#children').show();
  $('span.jquery_out').text(gender+" -> "+age);
});
```

Hope someones got an answer, i'm sure its not a tricky one when in the know.
Thanks in advance.
Matt

Comment: What does your html look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your markup looks like but your jQuery can be greatly simplified.

Before I go on it's worth noting that what you have are basically form fields but you're using lists for them instead. This is far from ideal and I would suggest using a listbox (select) or radio buttons instead and then styling them to suit. There are plenty of jQuery plugins for sprucing up these form items such as [Fancy Radio Buttons With jQuery](http://theodin.co.uk/blog/design/fancy-radio-buttons-jquery.html) (see the [demo](http://theodin.co.uk/tools/tutorials/jqueryTutorial/fancyRadio/?)).

Then:

```
<div id="gender">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
</div>
<span class="jquery_out"></span>
```

Rather than using `:contains()` and multiple selectors it's easier to do:

```
var gender;
var age;
$("#gender :radio").click(function() {
  gender = $(this).val();
  update();
});

function update() {
  var text = gender || "";
  if (text.length > 0) {
    text += " -> ";
  }
  text += age || "";
  $("span.jquery_out").text(text);
}
```

The age markup and code is largely the same.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!. i need to start writing cleaner javascript markup for sure.

Comment: i'm having trouble using the =+ 
in my example i only used 3 variables, in truth i've got 12. it was all working fine until i tried adding the third and forth.  i'm not able to build the " -> " bit in the desired way. are you able to help with this?
many thanks 
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need to do is normalize where your data is in your html and make your functions so you can find it:

```
var gender;
var age;
var children;
$('#gender li').click(function() {
    gender = $(this).text(); //or some other selection to find the value
    $('#age').show();
    $('span.jquery_out').text(gender);
});
$('#age li').click(function() {
    age = $(this).text(); //or some other selection to find the value
    $('#children').show();
    $('span.jquery_out').text(gender+" -> "+age);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this style, removing the need for the variables:

```
$('#gender li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  $('#age').show();
  $('span.jquery_out').text($(this).text());
});
$('#age li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  $('#children').show();
  $('span.jquery_out').text($("#gender li.selected").text() + " -> " + $(this).text());
}
```

You're just assigning a CSS class to keep track, if you want to style it to indicate it's selected, can do that as a bonus.